# Strlen not returning the correct string length

Tags: php

I have a string with this content :

```
$myString = 'Câmara de Dirigentes Lojistas';
```

This string have 29 chars. BUT when i call strlen, it returns 30 ! Even when i call `var_dump($myString)`, that's the result :

```
114:string 'Câmara de Dirigentes Lojistas' (length=30)
```

What is going on here ? Maybe the problem is related to the special char `â` ?

Comment: `â` is two bytes. Welcome to UTF8, use [`mb_strlen()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php) and basically every other `mb_` function you see in the sidebar from now on.

Comment: @Sammitch Thank you, this did the trick !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue with the character `â` as it is a special character which uses a different encoding. Characters like this are actually double characters this is why its giving 30 and not 29

To fix this, you need to use `mb_strlen()` with encoding

```
$myString = 'Câmara de Dirigentes Lojistas';

echo mb_strlen($myString,'utf8')
```

**NOTE** : If `mb_strlen` is undefined, then you will have to enable `mb` extension in your php settings

Comment: I think the idea of "special characters" and "double characters" is a confusing way of looking at this. In some encodings, such as UTF-16, *all* characters take more than one byte; in others, such as ISO 8859-15, all representable characters take exactly one byte. None are really more "special" than others.

Answer (score 4):

That's the right behavior since you are using UTF-8 encoding.

Please see this note on [`strlen()` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php)

> Note:
>
> strlen() returns the number of bytes rather than the number of characters in a string.

As your string have multi-byte characters (â), PHP uses two bytes to represent it.

To have the right string length, you must use the [`mb_strlen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php) function:

```
mb_strlen("â"); // 1

strlen("â");    // 2
```

Answer (score 3):

There are several definitions of the "length" of a string, because there are a variety of tricks used to represent the huge range of accented characters, variants, and non-alphabetic scripts used around the world.

- The number of bytes the string takes up. This is the easiest to calculate, but not always what is expected. For instance, in UTF-16, every code point takes up either 2 or 4 bytes; in UTF-8, code points take up 1, 2, 3, or 4 bytes. This is what `strlen` and most PHP functions work with.
- The number of "code points": separate symbols in the character set. This is the next easiest, and the next most common, but is generally a compromise between bytes and "graphemes" (see below) - there aren't many cases where it's particularly useful to count `é` as 2 "characters" just because it's represented with a combining diacritic. In PHP you can use [`mb_strlen`](http://php.net/mb_strlen) to count these, telling it your string's character encoding.
- The number of "graphemes": separate symbols a reader would recognise. This is the most intuitive meaning, but the hardest for a computer to define. In PHP you can use [`grapheme_strlen`](http://php.net/grapheme_strlen), as long as you have ensured your string is encoded as UTF-8.

Comment: Pendantry: UTF-16 sometimes uses 4 bytes. `;)`

Comment: Also, h̻̫o̲ͅw͎̝̻̘ ͎̖͔͢l̵̥͙̩̻̺͍o̡̝̠͖̹͚͉̹n̸g̴̜̭̠͉̥ ͜i̶̠͖̼̦̗͚s̥̪̥͍̪̥͘ ̳͉̝̹̫͔͝t̫͇h̵i͉̬͇͔̟̣s̗͕̳͔̜ ̯̥̺͙̠s̨͇̝t͍̹̗r̦̮͢i̳̮͕͘ͅǹ̫̙̥̫̱̪̠g͖͚̥̳̜͕͟?̦̝͙̬̳̤̜̕

Comment: @Sammitch oops, so it does!

Comment: @Sammitch 16em 

Comment: @TomBlodget put a dollar in the "used ems" jar.

Answer (score -1):

Interestingly the `â` char exists in extended ascii, i.e. it can be represented by just one byte, you can try it with this code:

```
$str = utf8_decode('Câmara de Dirigentes Lojistas');
echo 'length is ' . strlen($str);
```

that will output `length is 29`.

So as you see the thing is that when a char is not plain ascii (127 char ascii table) then PHP assumes UTF-8 automatically.

Comment: Firstly, there is no one encoding called "extended ASCII"; there are several 8-bit encodings which are "ASCII-compatible", and some may have this character in. Secondly, PHP does not necessarily assume UTF-8 automatically, that depends on the encoding of the source file. Finally, the string `utf8_decode` is badly named, and frequently misused; it assumes the input is UTF-8 (which it might not be), and converts it to ISO 8859-1, which is not a particularly useful character set. Your example works because you ran it from a UTF-8 encoded file, and because `â` happens to exist in ISO 8859-1.

Comment: @IMSoP Sure there is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII - Nelson speaks about accented letters.

Comment: (Not my downvote here).

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner That article uses it as a synonym for "ASCII-compatible encodings", and notes that it is often criticised as ambiguous and misleading. Since there can be any number of these, it is impossible to say that any particular non-ASCII character "exists in extended ASCII". For instance, `â` is definitely not in [ISO 8859-5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-5), but that would meet the definition of "extended ASCII".

Comment: @IMSoP Yeah I know. I (for one) have always considered and being shown that accented letters are part of an extended character set, *just saying*.

Comment: @IMSoP I wasn't criticizing so please don't make this an argument. Edit: and you deleted the comment I was responding to; why?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Sorry, yes, I retracted that comment because I realised I was taking it too personally. I still stand by my downvote on the answer though.

Comment: This answer is composed entirely of bad information.